# How to Join more than 2 tables in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have 4 tables `users`, `user_details`, `categories` and `galleries` I want to show all record in one query. See below my table structure

**categories**

```
id
name
```

**users**

```
id
username
email
password
user_type
is_active (0 or 1)
created_at
modified_at
```

**user_details**

```
id
user_id
category_id
name
gender
address
phone
```

**galleries**

```
id
user_id
name
image
is_active
```

I want to get all the user information which user id=1 with user_details and category and show her/her all the is_active=1 images from the `galleries` table

Here is my code -

```
@user_details = User.eager_load(:Category,:Gallery,:UserDetail).where('users.id'=>20, 'users.is_active'=>1, 'users.user_type'=>2, 'galleries.is_active'=>1).first()
```

Here I am getting error message:

```
Association named 'Category' was not found on User; perhaps you misspelled it?
```

Actually I have associate `Category` in the `UserDetails` model. So I am unable to get the `Category` data. Please see my all models -

**category.rb**

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :UserDetail
end
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  #before_save :encrypt_password
  has_one :UserDetail, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :Gallery, dependent: :destroy
end
```

**user_detail.rb**

```
class UserDetail < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :User
  belongs_to :Category
end
```

**gallery.rb**

```
class Gallery < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :User
end
```

Let me know why `categories` table not joining. Please Help me for this query.

Comment: why you are defining associations like this has_many :UserDetail it should be has_many :user_details

Comment: No, My model association working fine. Also `UserDetail` working fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some things. Was in rush so was unable to verify syntax but should get you pretty close

1. Proper association naming - associations by convention should be the singular or plural lowercase snake_case of the model.  So Gallery should be

   class Gallery
     belongs_to :user

   class User
     has_many :galleries
2. Use includes to load the values and prevent n+1 queries

   User.includes(:categories, :user_detail, ,:user_detail)
3. Use scopes for your conditionals
   @user_details = User.eager_load(:Category,:Gallery,:UserDetail).where('users.id'=>20, 'users.is_active'=>1, 'users.user_type'=>2, 'galleries.is_active'=>1).first()

   class User
     scope :active, -> {where(is_active: 1)}
     class :of_type, -> (id) {  where(user_type: id) }
   end

Then something more like

```
User.active.of_type(2).includes(:categories, :user_detail, ,:user_detail, :galleries).where('galleries.is_active'=>1).first()
```